# How to open a WPF window from a Form and vice versa, and still having the VS debugger debug them?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-debugging, winforms-interop

Usually I open a new window like this:

```
        new Sensors(this).Show();
        this.Hide();
```

But this method doesn't work when I try to open a WPF window from a Form and vice versa, So I did this:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appAddress);
        this.Close();
```

The promblem when its done this way is that the debugger won't debug the new Form/Window.

Is there a way to do this without having this problem?

Comment: Just temporarily set the second window as the first to open. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work (untested)?

http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2008/07/29/open-a-wpf-window-from-winforms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1- of course the debugger will not work, cuz you make the **windows** open a new app, in the debug mode your app is working under **Visual Studio** 
2- i checked this problem and it works fine, thats mean you did something wrong, just check your reference.

Comment: 1- I know, thats why i asked.
2- What did you do?